# How to make rounded corner triangle in XAML

Tags: xaml, silverlight, expression-blend

How can I make a rounded corner triangle in XAML-Silverlight?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the below Path will solve your problem, Only you need to change the points of your triangle according to your requirement. For more idea about [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path.aspx)

```
 <Path Data="M 300 100 L 500 400 100 400 Z"
            StrokeThickness="48"
            StrokeLineJoin="Round"
            Stroke="Blue"
            Fill="Blue" />
```